# Vue components can't use scss in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass, gulp, vue-component

I want to use globally `.scss` file in single `.vue` component

I'm using `gulp（laravel-elixir` to compile `sass/scss` and it's no problem. I can do all style anywhere in Laravel blade：

```
elixir((mix) => {
.sass('events/test/test.scss', 'public/css/events')
.compass('app.scss', 'public/css', {
style: 'nested',
sass: 'resources/assets/sass',
image: 'public/images',
javascript: 'resources/assets/js',
sourcemap: true,
comments: true,
relative: false,
})
}
```

**But the pain point is single "Vue component" I wrote that in Laravel 5.3（Key point is  ignore wrong part.）：**

```
<template></template>
<style lang="scss" >
</style>
<script></script>
```

I try these method to solevd this problem, but **still stuck**：

1. npm install -D sass-loader node-sass（SASS & SCSS, RefUrl：https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass）
2. Using SASS in Vue Components with Laravel Mix（RefUrl：https://serversideup.net/using-sass-vue-components....../）
3. google & stackoverflow any answer I did a lot of method ...

＊The terminal error log：

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'scss-loader' in /xxx/xxx/xxx/Test.vue

＊package.json（main）：

```
"sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
"scss-loader": "0.0.1",
"vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.3.2",
"vue-html-loader": "^1.1.0",
"vue-loader": "^8.7.1",
"vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
```

Comment: What's your webpack configuration?

Comment: Laravel-Mix should come with your laravel installation and is preconfigured to work with Vue single file components. Remove scss-loader, though - it's unnecessary. All you need is `npm i -D laravel-mix node-sass sass-loader`

Comment: I'm using laravel v5.3 and the v5.3 supports gulp not webpack：

- Laravel 5.3 **`=>`Laravel Elixir**`（Gulp）`
- Laravel 5.4 **`=>`Laravel Mix**`（Webpack）`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by following this in the documentation: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade#vue-component-sass-preprocessing

`npm install sass sass-loader`